# Changing single data in matrix with vector

Tags: r

Suppose I want to change the following matrix:

```
a= matrix(c(
  1:20),ncol=5)
a
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]    1    5    9   13   17
[2,]    2    6   10   14   18
[3,]    3    7   11   15   19
[4,]    4    8   12   16   20

rvec= c(4,2)
cvec=c(1,5)
a[rvec,cvec] = c(200,500)
a
    [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]    1    5    9   13   17
[2,]  500    6   10   14  500
[3,]    3    7   11   15   19
[4,]  200    8   12   16  200
```

but I want:

```
    [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]    1    5    9   13   17
[2,]    2    6   10   14  500
[3,]    3    7   11   15   19
[4,]  200    8   12   16  20
```

Considering the vector as a position of values  -  changing x,y (4,1) and x,y (2,5) to  in  `c(200,500)` respectively.

I can do that with for loops but it is too slow.

```
 for(i in 1:length(c(200,500)))
 {
   a[rvec[i],cvec[i]] = c(200,500)[i]
 }

 a
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]    1    5    9   13   17
[2,]    2    6   10   14  500
[3,]    3    7   11   15   19
[4,]  200    8   12   16   20
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
## Set up a matrix with row-indices in column 1 & column-indices in column 2 
ij <- rbind(c(4,1), c(2,5))

## Use it to pick out individual elements of a
a[ij] <- c(200, 500)

## Check that it worked
a
#      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
# [1,]    1    5    9   13   17
# [2,]    2    6   10   14  500
# [3,]    3    7   11   15   19
# [4,]  200    8   12   16   20
```

This is, by the way, documented in `?"["`:

> A third form of indexing is via a numeric matrix with the one
>        column for each dimension: each row of the index matrix then
>        selects a single element of the array, and the result is a vector.